# VBA using cell values instead of cell names

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I can select a range when I have cell names.  For example `Range(A1:B30).select` in VBA.

Is there a way to select a range with values written in the cells? I know the following code does NOT work but only that you know what I mean. `Range(217:216,9).select`.

I want to search for a value and specify the range but how can I do this?

I have already searched the web but I can not find a solution. I also tried to record the macro but it only recorded the code with cell names. I am new to VBA and I can't find a solution for my problem somewhere else. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: You will need to Loop inside all cells where you want to search that value, and then get the address of that cell.

Comment: Have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.Match Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-match-method-excel) eg get the row number of a specific value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we have:

[image]

and we want the range with values between (and including) *10* and *20*.  This code:

```
Sub RangeFromValues()
    Dim v1 As Long, v2 As Long
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, rng As Range

    v1 = 10
    v2 = 20
    Set r1 = Range("A:A").Find(what:=v1, after:=Range("A1"))
    Set r2 = Range("A:A").Find(what:=v2, after:=r1)

    Set rng = Range(r1, r2)
    rng.Select
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works perfectly fine. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Range("1:10").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
End Sub
```

would select only the values, which are not formulas in the first 10 rows:

[image]

To select the formulas: type `xlCellTypeFormulas` instead of `xlCellTypeConstants`. Just note, that if you do not have anything to `Select`, it would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, you only need to specify `x` (low boundary), `y` (upper boundary) and `rngTest` (range where you wish to select cells):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim rngTest As Range
    Set rngTest = Range("A1:J20"): x = 5: y = 10
    Call RangebyValue(x, y, rngTest)
End Sub
Private Sub RangebyValue(ByVal x As Long, _
                         ByVal y As Long, _
                         ByVal rngTest As Range)
    Dim vArr(), i As Long, j As Long, rngSelect As Range
    vArr = rngTest.Value
    For i = LBound(vArr, 1) To UBound(vArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(vArr, 2) To UBound(vArr, 2)
            If vArr(i, j) >= x And vArr(i, j) <= y Then
                If Not rngSelect Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngSelect = Union(rngSelect, rngTest.Cells(i, j))
                Else
                    Set rngSelect = rngTest.Cells(i, j)
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngSelect.Select
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Vityata's solution would work well to select all cells that have any value. If you are trying to find a specific value,

Following @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, 
I would recommend using a loop through those cells. 
For example:

```
Sub findTheNine()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Range("I7:L11")
        If rng.Value = 9 Then
            rng.Select
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

However, this would only select one of the '9's you wanted to find